# Oracle warning:execution completed with warning

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to enforce some constraints on wokson_staff table with writing below trigger, but I'm getting the following error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "Select" when expecting one of the following:
>   (-+case mpd mew mot null............)

Can anyone help me with it to figure out what is wrong with my trigger?

Thanks

```
Create or replace trigger Emp_cons
Before Insert on WorksON_Staff
For each row          
begin
where exists( SELECT worksON_staff.AssignmentNo, worksON_staff.StaffNo,
               staff.stafftype
                   FROM worksON_Staff,staff,workassignment
                  WHERE worksON.assignmentNo=worksON_staff.assignmentNo
                  and staff.staffNo=worksON_staff.staffNo
                  and
                  staff.stafftype ='supervisor'
                       INTERSECT 
                 SELECT worksON_staff.AssignmentNo,        worksON_staff.StaffNo,staff.stafftype
                   FROM worksON_Staff,staff,workassignment
                  WHERE
                  worksON.assignmentNo=worksON_staff.assignmentNo
                  and staff.staffNo=worksON_staff.staffNo
                  and
                  staff.stafftype ='authorizer') 
                  Then raise_error('71001', 'blahblablah');

end Emp_cons;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
    Create or replace trigger Emp_cons
    Before Insert on WorksON_Staff
    For each row
    declare  
    x number;            
    begin
    select count(*) into x from ( 
              SELECT :new.AssignmentNo,:new.StaffNo, staff.stafftype
              FROM staff,workassignment worksON
              WHERE worksON.assignmentNo=:new.assignmentNo
              and staff.staffNo=:new.staffNo
              and
              staff.stafftype ='supervisor'
                   INTERSECT 
              SELECT :new.AssignmentNo,:new.StaffNo,staff.stafftype
              FROM staff,workassignment worksON
              WHERE worksON.assignmentNo=:new.assignmentNo
              and staff.staffNo=:new.staffNo
              and
              staff.stafftype ='authorizer');

if (x>0) then
  --do your raise error procedure
end if;
```

Comment: This trigger code will compile but it will hurl Mutating Table exceptions.  This is because it queries the table which owns it.

Comment: @user1360341 ,you can reference the value to be inserted in the table using :new.column_name for example :new.AssignmentNo since that is the correct way and will avoid Mutating Table exceptions

Comment: I am getting an error when I have added : new . : Bind Variable "new" is NOT DECLARED

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is syntactically wrong by starting with 
where exists

are you missing a select statement before that??

Comment: No I'm not missing any select statement. does it mean that I cannot start my trigger with where exist condition?

Comment: Yes, you cannot start that way.that is not a valid syntax